# Android Disply TextView on top of screen whenever copied text from the any social media or any mail or any kind of EditText

Tags: android, service, textview, copy, paste

I got the value of the copied text like copied from the any messenger or mail or other social media,like i write in messenger hello,i, copied that now i display that in toast message( all code in service so it works in backgrounds),it done, now i want to display this value in Textview on top of the screen, whenever i copied text from the media ,one textbox automatically opend on top of the screen and display my copied value, how to create this type of textbox,open on top of screen  when every time copied value ? i need quick help,so please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you checking clipBoard data continuously using service?

Comment: in my service,when ever user user doing work with clipboard like copy,paste my service called any paste that data, now that i display in toast, but i want to whenever any copied that,it display in one textview, that display in top of screen.

Comment: So your problem is just how to display a `TextView` on top of your screen?

Comment: ya,now i want that,in quick of copy text from the any media, you have any solution then help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following to add a `TextView` to the top of the screen

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

TextView view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
view.setText(your_clipboard_text);
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

windowManager.addView(view, params);
```

`R.layout.activity_main` is any layout that you want to show, in your case just a `TextView` in an XML

You will also need to add the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />` in your manifest.

Comment: ok,thanks @Apoorv, it very useful to me, i done my work through this, if i want in this this text display for specific time and then gone the i used Timer na ??

Comment: Yes you can use a `CountdownTimer`.

Comment: You'll have to post a new question for that along with code and stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

- get windowManager in your service.
- Add a TextView with your copied text on window.

Now you will have to take care to remove that view from window when done.

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_u_wish, flag, PixelFormat.*);
windowManager.addView(view, layoutParams);
```

Remove-

```
windowManager.removeView(view);
```

Comment: you have any example of it ??

Comment: @NiravMehta check now